# How to use a PHP library with namespacing without Composer as dependency (PSR-0)?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I need to use some PHP libraries with dependencies but I have some restrictions on the webserver of the client. It is a managed webserver and I can not use a console eg over SSH.

So how do I use now these libraries without Composer?
Can I create some directories manually and what directories or paths do I need to create?
Also, what do I need to create so autoloading and namespacing is working?

Can I create the autoload.php somehow manually and what is the content of the file?

Comment: The accepted answer is PSR-0 compliant, for a PSR-4 solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571391/psr4-auto-load-without-composer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible with a simple autoloader and it is not so hard to do it:

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    // $fileName .= $className . '.php'; //sometimes you need a custom structure
    //require_once "library/class.php"; //or include a class manually
    require $fileName;

}
```

But sometimes you have to adjust the `$fileName` so it works with all libraries. It depends on the standard for autoloading and how the class names of the libraries are named. Sometimes you have to split the classname on `_` and use the first element for the direcotry name and add this also to the class name. I had for example a second library with a class like `Library_Parser` but the structure was `Library/library-parser.php`.

The first library worked directly with the above code and all classes were automatically loaded.

The code was taken from http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/ but I had to correct some code parts (additional underscores and backslashes). I have used the PSR-0 Standard solution.

PSR-4 version by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740659/thibault:

```
function loadPackage($dir)
{
    $composer = json_decode(file_get_contents("$dir/composer.json"), 1);
    $namespaces = $composer['autoload']['psr-4'];

    // Foreach namespace specified in the composer, load the given classes
    foreach ($namespaces as $namespace => $classpaths) {
        if (!is_array($classpaths)) {
            $classpaths = array($classpaths);
        }
        spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) use ($namespace, $classpaths, $dir) {
            // Check if the namespace matches the class we are looking for
            if (preg_match("#^".preg_quote($namespace)."#", $classname)) {
                // Remove the namespace from the file path since it's psr4
                $classname = str_replace($namespace, "", $classname);
                $filename = preg_replace("#\\\\#", "/", $classname).".php";
                foreach ($classpaths as $classpath) {
                    $fullpath = $dir."/".$classpath."/$filename";
                    if (file_exists($fullpath)) {
                        include_once $fullpath;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

loadPackage(__DIR__."/vendor/project");

new CompanyName\PackageName\Test();
```

Comment: For a PSR-4 solution, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571391/psr4-auto-load-without-composer