# Interface '...' not found in (PHP SQL Query Builder)

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use P[HP SQL Query Builder](https://github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder) in a project I'm working on. I am installing it manually. I did this by copying the src directory into my project and then using the following code within my class:

`$this->builder = new NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\GenericBuilder();`

The error I get whenever the builder is used is:

```
[18-Apr-2017 12:57:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\BuilderInterface' not found in /home/thomassm/public_html/php/lib/sqlbuilder/Builder/GenericBuilder.php on line 24
```

**GenericBuilder.php**

```
namespace NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder;

use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder\Syntax\WriterFactory;
use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Manipulation\AbstractBaseQuery;
use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Manipulation\QueryInterface;
use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Manipulation\QueryFactory;
use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Manipulation\Select;
use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Syntax\Column;
use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Syntax\Table;

/**
 * Class Generic.
 */
class GenericBuilder implements BuilderInterface
{//...}
```

**BuilderInterface.php**

```
namespace NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Builder;

use NilPortugues\Sql\QueryBuilder\Manipulation\QueryInterface;

/**
 * Interface BuilderInterface.
 */
interface BuilderInterface
{
    /**
     * @param QueryInterface $query
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function write(QueryInterface $query);

    /**
     * @param QueryInterface $query
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function writeFormatted(QueryInterface $query);
}
```

I assume the error is somehow caused by the way the files are called, any suggestions?

Comment: from the docs : The recommended way to install the SQL Query Builder is through Composer., why you do install the package manually?

Comment: Did you use an autolader ? Your class is not loaded (to be sure, you can check with the php function get_included_files [doc here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-included-files.php). Then you should use the composer autoloader [doc here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).  Or you can create and use your own autoloader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am installing it manually. I did this by copying the src directory into my project and then using the following code within my class: ...

Every source file should be included through [`include`/`requrie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) before using. But PHP allow to setup [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) for classes, interfaces and traits. In short, when runtime meets an undefined class then a special callback invokes, which can load the relevant file.

Although formally the autoloading rules can be arbitrary, but most of the modern projects supports the common community standard: [PSR-4 Autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). So, you need an implementation of this standard.

As said in the library description, the recommended way to install is through [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/):

```
php composer.phar require nilportugues/sql-query-builder
```

Composer provides own PSR-4 implementation and generates file `vendor/autoload.php`. Usually this file included at the application entry point. It allow using the classes from all required libraries.

You *can* use the packages without the Composer ([relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571391/psr4-auto-load-without-composer)). But it requires a lot of work (you still need an PSR-4 autoloader) and this way is rarely used today.

Comment: This may sound a little basic, by can you explain Composers to me. I can't find any good really basic explanation for them (baring in mind I'm going way out of my league using this stuff considering I'm only an A-Level student). What does a Composer actually do? Arrange files in your project directory or set up your web space with those files for you to use? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Sorry, but I can hardly explain better than described in the official [introduction](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I guess I will just have to have a shot at it and hope I get it correct and don't blow something up in the process :)